# Error while deploying Hadoop cluster (tutorial): The resource 'projects/project-id was not found

Tags: google-app-engine, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

Good morning, I am new to the Google Cloud Platform.
I am trying to follow the [tutorial to deploy an Hadoop Cluster](https://developers.google.com/hadoop/) and I am experiencing some problems.
I have installed the Cloud SDK, created a new project from the web interface, created a new bucket, enabled billing, obtained the permission "Can edit" (default), generated the pair of ssh keys and put them in $HOME/.ssh/ and configured the bdutil_env.sh script to use my project and my bucket.

This is what happens when I execute some commands in the shell:

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

(I choose Allow in the web page opened ->You are now authenticated with the Google Cloud SDK!)
You are now logged in as myaddress@gmail.com.
Your current project is project-id.

My project-id is *wordcountex*.

Now every command that uses my project gets an error. For example:

```
$ gcutil getproject --project=project-id --cache_flag_values --dump_request_response
INFO: --request-start--
INFO: -headers-start-
INFO: accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
INFO: accept: application/json
INFO: user-agent: google-api-python-client/1.0
INFO: -headers-end-
INFO: -path-parameters-start-
INFO: project: wordcountex
INFO: -path-parameters-end-
INFO: body: None
INFO: query: ?alt=json
INFO: --request-end--
INFO: URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/wordcountex?alt=json
Error: The resource 'projects/project-id' was not found
```

What should I do now?

I have tried to follow some other guides (this suggested to remove multiple gmail accounts: I did it; it says to visit the Google Compute Engine page once from the console: what does it mean?).

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem enabling the Compute Engine API: Console -> My Project -> APIs & Auth -> APIs.